# Ruby and instantiate objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class named Fraction that calculates the harmonic sum. Basically, I want to be able to input a value, and then the program be able to calculate the harmonic sum up to that number. For example, if a user inputs 3 then I want the output to be "harmonic 1: 1/1, harmonic 2: 3/2, harmonic 3: 11/6". This is what I have for the method so far.

```
print "Enter a value for your harmonic sum: "
x = gets.chomp.to_i

def harmonic_sum(x)
    (1..x).inject(Fraction.new(0)) do |a, i|
    harmonic = Fraction.new(1, i)
    puts "h#{i}: #{harmonic + a}"

    a + harmonic
    end
end

puts harmonic_sum
```

I keep getting an error that my argument is wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `harmonic_sum` requieres a parameter, maybe `x`.

Comment: And what is `Fraction`?

Comment: Fraction is my class I created that calculates the harmonic sum

Comment: Then you need to include it

Comment: Please edit to reproduce the error message, including the line in which it occurred.

Comment: Okay I added the class I created as well.

Comment: The error says it's coming up in the line that includes "def harmonic_sum (x)". It says "wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)"

Comment: by the way, using proper indentation in your code makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Right here you get an input:

```
x = gets.chomp.to_i
```

Then you define the method which requires one argument:

```
def harmonic_sum(x)
```

but here you call it with no arguments:

```
puts harmonic_sum
```

Instead, use `puts harmonic_sum(x)`

Comment: Once I do that, it says I get an error in line 4 which is "def initialize (n, d)". It says "'initialize': wrong number of arguments (1 for 2) (ArgumentError)"

Comment: @Arayah yeah look at `Fraction.new(0)` - you're calling it with one argument but the Fraction initialize function needs 2